# Wordpress: Retrieving images attached to posts with 'post_parent'

Tags: wordpress

I've recently upgraded some of my sites to Wordpress 3.5.1, and have noticed that you're no longer able to use the get_posts() function together with the 'post_parent' attribute to get posts that have been attached to a particular post. It seems that the latest update no longer appends the post_parent field with the post ID in the database.

Previously, it was possible to obtain an image attached to a post using get_posts();

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);    
$thumbnails = get_posts($args);
```

However, as post_parent is no longer appended with the ID, this does not work.

I should also add that this occurs when setting the image in the 'Featured Image' meta box.

This all began when I tried to append an image with a title="" attribute, but I found that there was no longer a way of doing this.

Comment: please post some code, because what you are asking or saying doesn't make much sense

Comment: @David Chase: Just updated.

Comment: what is your goal? to get an image attached to a post/page or to get an image attached to post/page parent?

Comment: I need to get the image attached to the page, and also populate the title attribute of that image with it's own caption.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the image attached to the page why not use `get_the_post_thumbnail()`.

Please refer to this method in the codex [**here**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).

Comment: get_the_post_thumbail() returns the image with the alt text, but as of the latest update does not return the title attribute of an image.

Comment: in the new 3.5 WP you get caption, alt, and description that can all be edited for each image inside of the media library. Therefore they can all be retrieved.. Its up to you as the "developer" to assign them  how you want, what i mean is you have each image have an alt or title tag with post title data if you so desired..

Comment: That's correct, but you can't actually get the value of the caption field without manually querying the database with $wpdb->get_results() or similar. I just wondered of there is a new WP function that I missed but I guess not.

Comment: querying the database like that? you mean using `wp_query` or `get_posts` or putting inside a loop because `get the post thumbnail` takes a third paramater that deals with image attributes

Comment: Yeah, you have to first retrieve the caption in the first place to put it into the third parameter.